# What are all the different ways pilots can navigate?

Tags: navigation, ifr-navigation, radio-navigation, performance-based-navigation

What are all the different ways pilots can navigate? What are they in simple terms and their unique advantages/disadvantages?

EX:

1. Dead-reckoning?
2. VOR?
3. GPS?
4. ATC Directives?
5. Others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a broad question, but here goes...

### Visual Navigation

**Pilotage,** otherwise known as IFR (I Follow Roads). The pilot looks out the window and navigates using reference to the ground by observing landmarks (cities, roads, bodies of water, charted structures, etc). This can be done using any kind of map but an aviation sectional is recommended because it includes useful information such as the Maximum Elevation Figure for a given quadrant, as well as prominently-displayed airports and associated information.

**Dead reckoning.** The pilot plans a route to a destination (either direct or via waypoints) and calculates the proper heading to fly using a flight computer. This heading will take into account discrepancies between magnetic north and true north, winds aloft, etc. Because the winds and aircraft performance may change, the pilot will have to occasionally use pilotage to reconcile their planned route with their actual ground track.

---

### Instrument Navigation

There are various ground-based radio navigation aids. One of the very early methods was the **"A-N" system** where two radio transmitters continually broadcast either a Morse "A" (.-) or "N" (-.). If the pilot heard only a single tone, it meant they were directly between the transmitters and therefore on course; otherwise they would hear one letter stronger than the other. This system is not used anymore.

Then there are **Non-Directional Beacons**. An instrument in the airplane can listen for the radio signal and can point a needle directly TO the beacon but cannot provide any more information than that. A small number of NDBs still exist but they are not really used either.

A **VHF Omnidirectional Range** instrument can point to the VOR beacon *and* can display precisely which radial of the beacon the aircraft is on. If both are equipped with **Distance Measuring Equipment**, the instrument will also show the slant-range distance (i.e. length-of-hypoteneuse) to the beacon, which allows the pilot to precisely locate themselves in space.

An **Instrument Landing System** is two antennas, one providing lateral guidance to a runway and the other providing vertical guidance. The instrument in the aircraft indicates whether the the pilot is aligned with each radio signal or is off-course (and by how much).

Using VOR receivers, an aircraft can fly along defined airways in the sky.

If the aircraft is equipped with a suitable system, the pilot can navigate *directly* to a given waypoint. This is known as **Area Navigation** (RNAV).
The system may be an **Inertial Reference System** which is primed at startup with its initial location and then uses gyroscopes to track minute changes in the aircraft's acceleration, allowing it to determine its position throughout the flight. It could also be a Flight Management System which uses VOR-DME information to automatically navigate directly as opposed to along pre-defined airways. Or it could use the Global Positioning System (or other satellite constellation like GLONASS) to find its position over the Earth.
Depending on the aircraft, the FMS may provide guidance to the pilot about where to position the control surfaces to align with the planned route, or it may simply display the route relative to the aircraft on a "moving map" akin to a smartphone's map display and allow the pilot to correct course as they see fit.

---

### ATC Guidance

When in radar coverage, ATC can provide navigation services for the pilot by issuing headings—called **vectors**—for the pilot to fly. The pilot does not have to do any navigational work at all, but must trust ATC to guide them properly to their destination.

At some airports, where equipment and training allow, ATC may even be able to issue vectors all the way down final in lieu of the pilot navigating on a ground-based or RNAV approach procedure.

Comment: Also PBN, RNP, LPV

Comment: @mins: IIRC, RNP is a flavor of PBN, and both are just standards for how accurate your RNAV system has to be—they are not navigation systems in and of themselves. LPV uses an RNAV system with what are essentially ground-based GPS units to provide enhanced vertical precision but it is still a flavor of RNAV.

Comment: I'd say LPV, RNP and RNAV are flavors of PBN.

Comment: Pressure pattern navigation, doppler radar navigation?